# Populating a Bootstrap datepicker based on date a passed from controller not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-datepicker

Main problem solved however still can't get datepicker to disable. More info at bottom of post.

I'm using MVC 5 and trying to use a `bootstrap datepicker` on one of my forms.

My view works like this: I have a ID number field that when populated with a valid ID from my country (which takes the form of `yymmddxxxxxxx`), needs to disable the `datepicker` (or stop the datepicker from showing so that the user can't edit this field once a valid ID number has been entered), make the `datepicker` field (DateOfBirth) `readonly` and populate the field with the date of birth in format `yyyy-mm-dd.`

Currently, I use a ajax call back to my controller which calls a class which verifies the ID number and returns it as something like `yyyy/mm/dd (12:00:00)` and also passes back the gender gotten from the ID number. I then, in the controller, just grab the `yyyy/mm/dd`, as well as the gender and pass that back to my view as a string via `json`.

All that works fine, however here is where my problem comes in. I now want to pass the DOB to the `datepicker` and I've tried a number of different ways, but I can't get it to format correctly as the datepicker gets today's date. I read that I should use `$.datepicker.parseDate()`, however I can't get that to work, either I get a typeerror `$.datepicker is not defined` or `parseDate is not a function` depending on how I try to fiddle with it.

I'm not sure what other info I need to give besides above. Below is my code.

**-View-**

```
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Birth:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Select Date", @tabindex = "8"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </div>
        </div>
```

**-Controller-**

```
    public ActionResult GetDOBID(string idNo)
    {
        SAIdNumber CheckNumber = new SAIdNumber(idNo);

        if (CheckNumber.IsValid == true)
        {
            string dob = CheckNumber.DateOfBirth.ToString();
            dob = dob.Substring(0, 10);

            return Json(new
            {
                gender = CheckNumber.Gender,
                DOB = dob
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(new { gender = "fail", DOB = "fail" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**-Js-**

```
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"

        });  

  $('#IdNumber').on('focusout', function () {
        var idNum = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDOBID", "Client")',
            data: { idNo: idNum },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.gender === "fail" || data.DOB === "fail") {

                        $('#Gender').removeAttr('readonly').val('');
                        $('#DateOfBirth').removeAttr('readonly').val('');
                        $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker('enable');
                }
                else {
                        $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker("disable");
                    var gend = 'F';
                    var date = new Date(data.DOB).toString('yy-mm-dd');

                    if (data.gender.toString() === '1') {
                        gend = 'M';
                    }

                    $('#Gender').val(gend);
                        $('#Gender').attr('readonly', true);

                    $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker('setValue', date);
                    $('#DateOfBirth').attr('readonly', true);

                }
            }
        })
    });
```

I know that this line `var date = new Date(data.DOB).toString('yy-mm-dd');` is wrong at least because DOB is already passed as a string, however I don't think I'm supposed to use this line at all, it was done by a colleague before I got to it and according to him apparently used to work but didn't when I got to having to work on the screen.

I also want to have this datepicker have today's date as the maximum date but I can't seem to get that to work either. I've tried initializing it with `maxDate: 0 or '0'` but that hasn't worked.

When editing a user on this page, I also need the datepicker to be auto filled with the DOB from the database which is also yyyy-mm-dd however I assume once the major problem being experienced and formatting issue is solved won't be a problem anymore.

Thanks in advance and let me know if I need to provide anymore information.

EDIT:
I've done a basic [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMzLG/35/) to show what it should do using jquery UI, however I'm using bootstrap datepicker and doing the exact same thing in my code doesn't work. I get a date like `08/27/19` filling the field.

**EDIT 2:**

Well I managed to fix the populating problem my self when I had a realisation while doing some testing that the bootsrap datepicker doesn't use `dateFormat:` as a parameter and that is should be `format:`.

However I still can't get the datepicker to be disabled so that it doesn't show. It needs to not show so that a user can't edit the date in the readonly field by using the datepicker once.

using `$('#DateOfBirth').datepicker('disable');` or `$('#DateOfBirth').datepicker('options: 'disabled');` doesn't work and I can't get a function on show using `preventdefault` to work either.

**Edit 3:**

Well, Even though no one replied I'm updating this thread with my answer. I managed to fix the problem kind of by disabling the dates of the week. So if anyone wants to do something similar they can have a look at my answer below, However I'd still appreciate any other suggestions with regards to a better way to disable the picker. It's only an issue with bootstrap datepicker. Anyway, See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my JS where I disabled the days of the week, see original topic for what my problems were and how I fixed them below:

```
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            autoclose: true
        });

        $('#IdNumber').on('focusout', function () {
        var idNum = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDOBID", "Client")',
            data: { idNo: idNum },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.gender === "fail" || data.DOB === "fail") {

                        $('#Gender').removeAttr('readonly').val('');
                        $('#DateOfBirth').removeAttr('readonly').val('');

                        $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekDisabled', '');
                }
                else {
                    var gend = 'F';
                    if (data.gender.toString() === '1') {
                        gend = 'M';
                    }
                    pickerEnabled = false;
                    $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker('setDaysOfWeekDisabled', '0,1,2,3,4,5,6');
                    $('#Gender').val(gend);
                    $('#Gender').attr('readonly', true);
                    var date = data.DOB;
                    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({ pickTime: false });
                    $('#DateOfBirth').attr('readonly', true);
                    $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker('setDate', date);
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: I believe setting the field to 'disabled' rather than 'readonly' will prevent editing of the value, either via datepicker or manual entry.  I just did a quick test on one of my forms, and setting 'disabled' to 'true' prevents me from even focusing in that field. Ahh... just realized that this will also prevent that from submitting with the form.  Perhaps a hidden field that gets the same value assigned can be passed to the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the hidden field idea, I will need to make quite a few changes in order for that to work, but this might be my best bet, as having a datepicker pop up with all the days disabled isn't exactly the greatest solution to present to someone.